# socket.io.min.js (failed) file not found

Tags: python, sockets, flask, socket.io

I am running into an error with flask-socketIO. I am trying to build a chat site. socket.io.min.js fails.

Here are the steps I am taking.

1. python main.py (loading the server)
2. refresh my index.html in chrome
3. opening developer tools to find that socket.io.min.js has failed

my main.py looks like

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecret'

socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
print('Message: ' + msg)
send(msg, broadcast=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

my index.html contains the following

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.5.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var socket = io.connect();
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            socket.send('user connected!');
        });
    </script>
```

I have tried many different cdns however nothing has helped. I still get
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the domain and the port to your io.connect function like it is described in the documentation of [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
    });
</script>
```